# How to search specific row for first 5 consecutive blank cells?

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble figuring out how to locate the first 5 consecutive blank cells in a specific row after column F.

The specific row number is found by searching column B in Sheet2 for a value selected from a drop down list in Sheet1, cell A1:

---

```
Dim myValue As Range 'value selected from a drop down list
Dim findRow As Range
Dim targetRow As Long

Set myValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") 'location of drop down list
Set findRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B").Find(What:=myValue, LookIn:=xlValues) 'searches column B in Sheet2 for the selected drop down list value
targetRow = findRow.Row

Sheets("Sheet2").Select

'// code to locate first 5 consecutive blank cells after column F //
```

---

How would I then search targetRow for the first 5 consecutive blank cells after column F?

Comment: Possibly add a screenshot of what your data looks like, or what type of data it is.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like so. Use SpecialCells to look for blank areas. Is it exactly 5 blanks or at least 5?

```
Sub x()

Dim myValue As Range 'value selected from a drop down list
Dim findRow As Range
Dim targetRow As Long
Dim r As Range

Set myValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") 'location of drop down list
Set findRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B").Find(What:=myValue, LookIn:=xlValues) 'searches column B in Sheet2 for the selected drop down list value
If Not findRow Is Nothing Then
    targetRow = findRow.Row
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        For Each r In .Range(.Cells(targetRow, "F"), .Cells(targetRow, .Columns.Count)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Areas
            If r.Count = 5 Then
                MsgBox r.Address
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next r
    End With
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: exactly 5 cells sir

Comment: Instead of a MsgBox displaying the location of the first 5 blank cells, how do I save the location of the first 5 blank cells so I can paste values into that range later? @SJR

Comment: Just assign another range variable `set r2=r`.

Comment: Ok I defined r2 as a range and then set r2 = r, but when I try to paste values  into that range (Sheets("Sheet2").Range(r2).Select, then myComment.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll) it gives me a run-time 1004 error "Application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: `r` is already a range you just need `r.pastespecial`. Don't follow what you are doing - what is mycomment?

Comment: @AlexB, SJR answered your original question. you wanted to find 5 consecutive blank cells. i suggest that you accept SJR's answer